# How get data from rest api URL in angularJs? While i'm try to get its show me as 0kb file

Tags: json, angularjs

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/api/Country')
        .success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        }).error(function(data, status){
            alert('Error');
        });
}
```

URL: Try pull the data from url, it shown me as a 0kb file. when i click that URL directly in shown some data.

Comment: Is there an XMLHttpRequest error in your console?

Comment: If you change your URL with localhost, it is no longer possible for us to help you on that ... is your problem solved ?

Comment: Could you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Tried on my application before you replace the url by localhost (I guess changed for security reason), seems to come from a wrong configuration on server side, not angular.

Firefox trigger an error saying :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/api/Country. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

If you are in charge of this server, you should give a look at Cross-Origin Request, but your angular code is correct, sorry :D